# Show that $\sup \{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} \}=1$ where $m, n$ natural.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $1$ is an upper bound, so a supremum exists. I can't show it. 
$1$ is $\sup(A)$ if for $v < 1$, then $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} > v$ for some $m$, $n$ naturals.

Comment: Hint: Pick $n = 1$. Suppose $v = 0.85$. How small would $m$ have to be to make $1/n - 1/m = 1 - 1/m$ be larger than 0.85? Try this for a couple of values of $v$, and you'll notice a pattern, and you're 90% of the way to a proof.

Comment: WLOG we can fix $n=1$.

For $v < 1$, we have $v < 1 - \frac{1}{m} \Leftrightarrow 1 < m(1-v)$. Can you construct an integer $m$ that depends on $v$ such that this inequality is always true? Hint: the floor and ceiling functions are your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $m$ so that $\frac1m<\varepsilon$. Then $1-\frac1m$ is an element of the given set (call it $A$), and $1-\frac1m>1-\varepsilon$, so that $\sup A\geqslant 1-\varepsilon$. It follows that $\sup A = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A:=\left\{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\right\}.$ Since $\sup A$ is the least upper bound of $A,$ then $\sup A\leq1.$ If $\sup A<1,$ then $$\dfrac{1}{k}<1-\sup A,$$ for some integer $k>0.$ This implies that $$\sup A<1-\dfrac{1}{k}\leq\sup A.$$

Answer (score 0):

$1$ is not special
and integers are not special.

If,
for $x > 0$,
$A(x)
=\sup_{m, n \ge x} (\frac1{n}-\frac1{m})
$,
$\sup(A)
=\frac1{x}
$
by the same argument:
look at
$\frac1{x} - \frac1{m}
$
for arbitrarily large $m$.

Though, since the $\sup$ is never reached,
I feel more comfortable
using $\lim \sup$.