# Let $S=\{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}:n,m\in \mathbb{N}\}$ Show that $\sup S = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

EDIT:
This question is not a duplicate because I am asking how to show that $1$ is the greatest upper bound of $S$ by using the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above.

Let $S=\{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}:n,m\in \mathbb{N}\}$
Show that $\sup S = 1$

To do this we must show that $1$ is an upper bound of $S$ and $1$ is the least upper bound of $S$.

To show it is an upper bound we know
$$n>0, n>\frac{1}{n}, and \frac{1}{n}\leq 1$$
$$\Rightarrow 0<\frac{1}{n}\leq1$$
$$\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\leq 1-\frac{1}{m}$$

Since $1-\frac{1}{m}<1, m\in\mathbb{N}$ we know $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} < 1$ so $1$ is an upper bound of $S$.

Now I'm stuck on showing that $1$ is the least upper bound. 
If we let $v\in\mathbb{R}$ be an upper bound of $S$ we want to show $1\leq v$. I am trying to do this by contradiction.

So we assume $v<1 \Leftrightarrow v-1<0\Leftrightarrow 0 <1-v$.

I have been told I can run into a contradiction by recalling that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above, but I'm not sure how to get to the contradiction.

Comment: We will prove that anything less than $1$ is not an upper bound... Let $v<1$ then, by some how, find $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $v+\frac{1}{n}<1$.. This can be done easily... Now, given any number $0<l<1$ there exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $l<\frac{1}{m}$... In case of $v+\frac{1}{n}$ we have $v<\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}$. So, we are done....

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403344/show-that-sup-frac1n-frac1m-1-where-m-n-natural/1403378#1403378

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there was another upper bound $\alpha$ with $\alpha<1$. Choose a positive integer $N$ large enough that $$\frac{1}{N}<1-\alpha.$$

(The fact that we can choose such an $N$ follows from the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above.)

But now the number

$$\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{N}>\alpha,$$

contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $S$, since the RHS of that expression is in $S$ ($n=1$ and $m=N$).

Answer (score 0):

Sup$(A-B)=$Sup$(A)-$Inf$(B)=1-0=1,$ where $A=\{\frac{1}{m}:m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$